# Problem to implement API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, import, view, gson

I need help to implement a list view from an API,
i need one more list to complete and make a get method.
This is for a project for faculty and i dont see solution on tutorials on internet
Here is code for information view :
package com.example.myapplication;

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;

public class TopScorer extends AppCompatActivity {
    SearchView searchView;
    ListView listView;
    String teams[] = {};

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_scorer);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            ArrayList<String> teamsInf = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                API API = new API(query);
                try {
                    API.execute().get();
                    teamsInf = API.getTeamsInfo();
                    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TopScorer.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teamsInf);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public class API extends AsyncTask {

        String teamName;
        ArrayList<String> teamsInfo;

        public API(String name) {
            this.teamsInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://heisenbug-premier-league-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/premierleague/team?name="+this.teamName)
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "6ad8dfcfcbmshb4a45a22532e4a1p1efecajsnc2fb433de0da")
                    .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "heisenbug-premier-league-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                    .build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(TopScorer.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                    int index=1;
                    String myResult = response.body().string();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Data responseResult=gson.fromJson(myResult, Data.class);
                    for (lst l : responseResult.Data())
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Liverpool: " + l.getTeam());
                        teamsInfo.add(String.valueOf(index) + ". " + l.getPlayed() + ": " + l.getWin());
                        teamsInfo.add("Draws : " + l.getDraw());
                        teamsInfo.add("Loss : " + l.getLoss());
                        teamsInfo.add("Goals Against : " + l.getGoalsAgainst());
                        teamsInfo.add("Goals For : " + l.getGoalsFor());
                        teamsInfo.add("Points : " + l.getPoints());
                        teamsInfo.add("");
                        index++;
                    }


                }
            });
            return null;
        }
        public ArrayList<String> getTeamsInfo()
        {
            return this.teamsInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is Data Class code:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Data {
    private String team;
    private String played;
    private String win;
    private String draw;
    private String loss;
    private String goalsFor;
    private String goalsAgainst;
    private String points;


    public String getTeam() {
        return this.team;
    }

    public String getPlayed() {
        return this.played;
    }

    public String getWin() {
        return this.win;
    }

    public String getDraw() {
        return this.draw;
    }

    public String getLoss() {
        return this.loss;
    }

    public String getGoalsFor() {
        return this.goalsFor;
    }

    public String getGoalsAgainst() {
        return this.goalsAgainst;
    }

    public String getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }

    public Data fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Data team = new Data();
        try {
            team.team = jsonObject.getString("team");
            team.played = jsonObject.getString("played");
            team.win = jsonObject.getString("win");
            team.draw = jsonObject.getString("draw");
            team.loss = jsonObject.getString("loss");
            team.goalsFor = jsonObject.getString("goalsFor");
            team.goalsAgainst = jsonObject.getString("goalsAgainst");
            team.points = jsonObject.getString("points");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return team;
    }
}
```

can anyone help me, i prefered to implement api respone with okhttp code

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is? What exactly does not work?

Comment: When you run a slow network task you cannot immediately retrieve the result. It will either block the UI thread (bad) or return an empty result before the background task runs. For an AsyncTask you cannot do anything with the result until `onPostExecute`, which you have not implemented.

Comment: The problem is : i need class Data is a class of objects of my api response (Football teams), i need to create a somehow a list in Data where i will store this objects, and for " responseResult.Data()" program can't resolve Date() in class Data, or if you have some exemple or code to display my response in a listview i would be gratefull, im new in the android studio and java and our professor doesen't explained to us .